Need guidance on which tool is suitable to build an app/website whichever takes less time
I'm not a coder, but a management student. I have opted for a course Agile Software Development Methodology. Now Working on a college project to create a library book borrowing app/website(hosted or local server). I have a fixed list of users and books stored in Google Sheets.
Goal: User Authentication: Users should log in using their roll number. Book Inventory: The app should display a list of available books and their status (available/issued). Book Borrowing Request: Users can select books and send a borrowing request(by clicking "send request button") to the library via email.
Constraints: Time: I have a tight deadline of 2-3 weeks. Technical Expertise: I'm a beginner with limited to no coding experience.
What I have tried so far: I have asked ChatGPT to help me with Google Sheets and MIT App Inventor, but somehow the .js code which was shared by GPT to link Google Sheets API to MIT App doesn't work hence the app stands unusable.
Request: I'm looking for guidance on the most efficient way to develop this app/website within the given constraints. I'm open to using no-code or low-code platforms to speed up the development process.
Specific Questions:
Recommended No-Code/Low-Code Platforms: Which platforms are suitable for this project?
Data Integration: How can I integrate Excel/Google Sheets data into the app?
User Interface Design: What are the best practices for designing a user-friendly interface?
Email Integration: How can I implement email functionality to send borrowing requests to the librarian?
Any advice and code snippets/cloud platforms/or anything else would be greatly appreciated.

What is the goal of the studies, as projected by the university? Is it aimed at learning how to program? What is your goal? Just pass the exam as quickly with as little effort as possible?

Lesson #1 - ChatGPT is not at atll suitable for coding. It can lead you onto right track, but that's it - "somehow" is a wrong word to describe the non-working state. You are asking way to many questions at once for a sensible recommendation. TLDR answer- Wordpress with plugins will likely manage, but you'll likel get a bad note for such approach to the project, unless it's just "do anything as long it works".

@ThomasWeller thanks for asking. The goal of the course is to teach agile project development and management to the students and how the corporates work. Hence the instructor wants us(I am working in a team, non of them is a coder) to develop a app our choosen topic and apply agile principles learned during lectures at the uni.

@Destroy666 thank you for suggesting new tool, Wordpress. I'll surly look into it. And speaking of the approach. The instructor deliberately gave us short deadline as they want to demonstrate how tech companies mess up on tight deadlines with a broken app presented to the client. Hence, giving a understanding of agile framework and teamwork.

For a no-code solution, I’d recommend Bubble or Glide — they’re great for building apps quickly without needing to code. Glide integrates really well with Google Sheets, so it might be a good fit for your project. If you want more flexibility down the line, Bubble would be awesome, but it might take a little more time to get used to.
For data integration, tools like Zapier or Make can help you sync Google Sheets with your app. You could set up something to update book status and send borrowing requests via email, too. It might sound like a lot, but these platforms make it easy!
For UI design, try to keep things super simple and focus on what users need. Keep navigation clean, like a basic list of books with available/issued status. No need to overcomplicate!
As for email functionality, Zapier can connect Google Sheets with an email service to send out requests automatically. It's pretty straightforward once you set up a trigger for new entries in your sheet.
On a side note, I recently started freelancing and offering web development services to clients, and I’ve been using Cloudways to manage all my websites. I actually got it at a discount during Black Friday, and so far, it’s been great! What I like is that it lets me manage multiple client sites from one platform, and the costs are pretty decent too. I’m not looking to switch anytime soon—probably sticking with it for at least 4-5 months.
